# Disable maven checkstyle

Tags: maven, checkstyle

I want to execute a maven target but checkstyle errors forbids that. I have no time right now to correct checkstyle error (my checkstyle rules have been recently updated and I can't handle all of them right now).

Is there a way to disable checkstyle operation and execute my goal anyway ?

Answer (score 317):

Solution is : `mvn [target] -Dcheckstyle.skip`.

I like this solution as it is temporary and do not require editing of pom files, or anything that can be versioned.

Comment: mvn [target] -D"checkstyle.skip"=true (if you are using Powershell)

Comment: Even this, the maven checkstyle still executes, How can I disable it so I can speed up compile without edit pom

Comment: [Constantin Konstantinidis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6161244/constantin-konstantinidis): This does not work for mvn quarkus:dev -Dcheckstyle.skip

Comment: it does not work on mvn eclipse:eclipse command

Comment: or mvn --% [target] -Dcheckstyle.skip for PowerShell 3.0 and above (to disable parsing of parameters)

Answer (score 30):

RandomCoders answer is the preferred one.

If you want to disable checkstyle from your pom, you can add the checkstyle plugin to the pom and set the skip flag to prevent the check.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 24):

In one line:

```
<properties>
  <checkstyle.skip>true</checkstyle.skip>
</properties>
```

Comment: It's `<skip.checkstyle>` for my project.

Comment: Can you indicate maven and plugin versions ?

Answer (score 11):

If you want to disable checkstyle from pom, you can add checkstyle plugin to your pom and set execution phase to none. Important thing for me was that I have to set id exactly the same as in parent pom. In othercase it doesn't works.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>checkstyle-validation</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

The presented solutions are for the whole project/module, however I needed to have checkstyle skipped only for a certain class.
So I just want to share the solution I've found.
If you dont want to exclude the whole module and only a particular class, you can add the exclusion in the pom like following:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>path/to/your/class/from/sources/root/myclass.java</excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```